# Desmarcar RadioButtonFor asp.mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, radiobutton

Saludos tengo el siguiente inconveniente: estoy programando un quiz en ASP MVC seleccionando las respuestas mediante un RadioButtonFor, el problema es que una vez marcado una opción no puedo desmarcar. Como puedo resolver esto?.

Muchas gracias!

```
<div class="container">
    <form id="contact" action="" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.TEXTO)</h3>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA1, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA1</h3>
            <input type="radio"
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA2, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA2</h3>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA3, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA3</h3>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <h3>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.PREGUNTA4, @Model.ID) @Model.PREGUNTA4</h3>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset >
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RESPUESTA)
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <button name="submits" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Continuar</button>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, creo que una vez que marcas un radio, la propiedad nativa te dice que "no se puede desmarcar ninguna opción que corresponda a ese FOR", creo que para tu función tendrías 2 opciones: 1.-Crear un grupo de CheckBox con una función en javascript o JQuery que simule ser un radiobuttongroup 2.-Colocar un botón aparte que limpie tu formulario. 
Si estas de acuerdo con alguna de estas opciones publico mi respuesta.